# Как можно передать данные с react на nodejs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Вот это мой React - SignUp.js
я должен отправить данные с react а nodejs и сохранить users в MongoDB
Спасибо )

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class SignUp extends Component {
    state = { 
        email: '', 
        password: '',
        firstName: '',
        lastName: ''
    }
    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.id]: e.target.value
        })
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(this.state);
    }
    render() {
        return (
        <div className="container"> 
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="white">
                <h2>Вход</h2>
                <div className="input-field">
                    <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="firstName" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </div>
                <div className="input-field">
                    <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="lastName" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </div>
                <div className="input-field">
                    <label htmlFor="email">E-mail</label>
                    <input type="text" id="email" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </div>
                <div className="input-field">
                    <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </div>
                <div className="input-field">
                    <button className="btn pink lighten-3 z-depth-0">Войти</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
    }
}

export default SignUp
```

Answer (score 0):

Напишите API по которому будете отправлять свои данные на Node.js-сервер с помощью `Axios`, например.

Отправляете с React как-то так, навешиваете метод на кнопку отправки данных:

```
newUser = async () => {
    const query = await Axios.post("/newUser", this.state)
}
```

На сервере пишете что-то вроде:

```
app.post('/newUser', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body) //данные с клиента
})
```

Создать сервер достаточно просто.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ но consolelog не чего не выходит

Comment: @АлиНурлибеков прикрепите код серверной части

Comment: `const express = require('express')
const bp = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
const port = 5000

app.use( bp.json() )
app.use( bp.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}) )

app.use(express.json());     
app.use(express.urlencoded());

app.post('http://localhost:5000/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.query);
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
`

Comment: @АлиНурлибеков `app.post` должен содержать путь а не `url`,`app.post('/path')` и `req.query` используется когда приходит `get` запрос. В таком случае с react нужно отправлять запрос на `Axios.post('http://localhost:5000/path', this.state)`

Comment: При нажатии на кнопку- это логин и логоут

Comment: https://prnt.sc/w6dc9l это сервер